# Button like click effect for Imageview in android

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I'm having an imageview which will navigate to another page once it is clicked. Right now when it is clicked user will not be getting any feel that it is clicked. So what i want is to have some effect (like in normal button) at the time of click on the image....can anyone help me?

Comment: You could just set the image to a button but using a selector is probably easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a selector like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
            <solid android:color="#151B8D" />

            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#151B8D" />

            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:topLeftRadius="0dp" android:topRightRadius="8dp" />

            <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
        </shape></item>
    <item><shape>
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#151B8D" android:startColor="#151B8D" />

            <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#000000" />

            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:topLeftRadius="0dp" android:topRightRadius="8dp" />

            <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 7):

use  **style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"** in the xml file. 
It will show android default click effect.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
    />
```

Comment: That changes the width of the Imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to physical not visible feel, use something like this to make a sound and provide haptic feedback:

```
    iv.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY);
    iv.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
```

where iv is your imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about xml selector, here is the link which could you help [xml selector link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)