# Imageview on-touch/click effect without multiple effects (Android)

Tags: android, imageview

Is there away to show some kind of effect when imageview pressed. I use imageview as a button, so need to show some effect on touch. Many existing threads propose selectors with multiple images. This is too much work, because I have a lot of imageviews. I am also open to extending the imageview class. Any ideas or workaround.

Comment: have you seen `ImageButton` class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7176006

Comment: https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect

Comment: Thanks all. Imagebutton is not good, because I use this on a custom title bar. @saree, u have specified a way where I have to use a selector for each imageview. I like karan sugession.  But I was looking for like glow effect or some animation.

Comment: so what that you use this on a custom title bar?

Comment: Imagebutton is not flat.

Comment: so make a custom `ImageView` and use a selector as a background

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405272/button-like-click-effect-for-imageview-in-android

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a click function add

```
 ImageView img= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.theID);
 Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.alpha);
 img.startAnimation(animation);
```

Create an `anim` folder in Assets and then cleate an animation resource file named `alpha`

inside the file paste the following

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="50"
    android:fromAlpha="0.5"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

This type of animation just sets the Alpha tranparency to 50% and back to 100% so the image will flash.

There are many animations so have a look around on the net to find which one you like and create the anim resource file and put the name here  `R.anim.alpha);`

in your imageView xml file you can add `android:onClick="myClickFunction"`

and then in the activity add

```
public void myClickFunction(View v) {
    ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.theID);
     Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.alpha);
     img.startAnimation(animation);   
}
```